# margins on monitor creating different effect

Tags: html, css, button

Here is a link to my webpage:

[Homepage](http://jobrangers.com/newtemplate/flatone-default/)

If you look, there are two boxes. One says "Get Started" and one says "Try it free". Here is the HTML I used to generate them:

```
    <div style="margin-top:-100px">
        <span style="margin-right:525px;font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;color:white;">Make money for a referral</span>
        <span style="margin-left:-15px;font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;color:white;">Hire the best candidate</span>
        <h5>
           <img src="images/bluuhorn.png" class="fa-image" style="margin-bottom:15px;padding:3px 0 0 0;width:140px;height:137px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <span style="font-size:20px;color:white;margin-right:205px;margin-left:205px">Explainer Video</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <img src="images/Company.png" class="fa-image" style="margin-bottom:15px;padding:3px 0 0 0;width:140px;height:137px">
        </h5>
    </div>                              
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" style="background-color:#25AAE1;width:245px;height:42px;margin-left:150px"><span style="color:white;font-size:18px">GET STARTED</span></button>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" style="background-color:#25AAE1;width:245px;height:42px;margin-left:470px"><span style="color:white;font-size:18px">TRY IT FREE</span></button>
</div>
```

Apparently this isn't going to work on every monitor. I imagine its due to the margins. How do I fix this so it comes up centered on every monitor?

A.) I expect it to be centered directly underneath the bars.
B.) I anticipate the problem is im setting `margin-left` to certain pixels and that isn't going to layout correctly on every type of monitor.

I'd like the images to be directly above the buttons-centered. Unfortunately, i set the buttons using margins and that's causing issues.

Comment: Please elaborate on the "this" in " this isn't going to work on every monitor" ie - please tell us: a) what you expect it to do and b) what you expect the problem to be.

Comment: Also note: most people will not click through to another site in order to see the problem. 1) there's far too much click-bait/spam on the web, and we've grown skittish 2) Stack Overflow questions should be *complete* in and of themselves. Links go stale, and we want the questions to still be valid and useful even after that.... So... that's why I'm asking you to put all relevant info into your question :)

Comment: On this page, I can see no bars for anything to be directly underneath (remember, I'm *not* clicking on the link). please make your explanation as though I have never looked at your homepage (which I haven't). Assume nothing. :)

Comment: @TarynEast i added the images html.

Comment: Yes, but you haven't yet explained what it should look like, or what you are trying to do - that's what I'm trying to coax out of you. ;) The information is inside your head, so it seems obvious to you... but it isn't here on the page... so it isn't at all obvious to anybody else what you are trying to do with this code ;)

Comment: @TarynEast does my latest update help?

Comment: Yes, the last sentence does help ;)

Comment: you've got some pretty odd indentation and nesting here... I've had a go at neatening it up to try and figure out what's indented to where. However, i think your fix is outlined by @alex.agat  - have a look at how Bootstrap does grid-layout, and you won't need your hard-coded stuff at all.

Comment: @TarynEast can we chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61808/discussion-between-jkushner-and-taryn-east).

Comment: Not really. sorry... I'm currently working. I have brief time periods where I can come and do other things - during running the test suite or on breaks, but otherwise not really time for a chat sorry.

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of issues with the site when the width drops below ~ 1100 px. You are using too many absolute widths defined in margins to make those components work for all window sizes.

The site is already built using the [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) framework. Therefore read up on how you setup columns and rows and put the elements in your top section into columns to get this stuff to flow properly.

Comment: its custom work though so i dont think that its going to work with bootstrap. is there a way to handle this custom?

Comment: Bootstrap is just the framework, meaning just the building blocks. You can write any custom code on top of it so that your site functions and looks exactly as you want it to.

Comment: ok i used col-md-6 and now i need to center the elements below the images. how do i use custom code to center the columns i created. you can see the bars at the site.

Comment: are you interested in handling this? I can subsidize the work.

Comment: If you are inclined contact me through my website on my profile and we can further discuss. StackOverflow is more for Q&A